# What are the Grim revenge spell's "wight" stats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am trying to figure out how the “wight” works for the grim revenge spell.

The spell states:

> The hand of the subject tears itself away from one of his arms, leaving a bloody stump.
>   This trauma deals 6d6 points of damage.
>   Then the hand, animated and floating in the air, begins to attack the subject.
>   The hand attacks as if it were a wight (see the Monster Manual) in terms of its statistics, special attacks, and special qualities, except that it is considered Tiny and gains a +4 bonus to AC and a +4 bonus on attack rolls.
>   The hand can be turned or rebuked as a wight.
>   If the hand is defeated, only a regenerate spell can restore the victim to normal.

Does this wight also need to be adjusted in other ways for the size? Aka does the damage for its slam attack move down two steps?

Do I look at the “improving monsters” information and move down from medium amending Dex and Str scores?

Answer (score 2):

Going Strictly by the spell description you would have:

- *attacks as a wight* -- Slam 1d4+1 and energy drain; HP 4d12(26)
- *considered tiny* -- can share it's space with one ally, can share a space with an enemy that is medium sized or larger. -8 on special attacks (grapple, shove, etc)
- *+4 to AC and attack* -- AC 19; to hit +7
- *can be turned as a wight* -- self explanitory

If you apply tiny to the wight instead:

- Str 8 Dex 16 HP 4d8(18)
- Slam attack 1d4-1 (min 1) and energey drain (1d4+3 if allowed dex to damage)
- AC 17, to hit +1 (+5 if allowed Dex)
- can share it's space with one ally, can share a space with an enemy that is medium sized or larger. -8 on special attacks (grapple, shove, etc)

So it appears the intent of the spell is the first option, however as a GM you can choose the second.